# estimating the $L^\infty$ of a covolution

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, convolution

I am trying to estimate the following convolution,
$$f_\epsilon(x)=\int f(x-y)\rho_\epsilon(y) dy$$
where $f(x)=(1-x^2)^{-1/4}\chi_B$ where $B$ is the unit ball ($|x|<1$) and $\rho_\epsilon=\epsilon^{-1}\rho(x/\epsilon)$ and $\rho$ is the standard approximation to the identity as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier).

I want to understand how the following norm behaves $\|f_\epsilon\|_\infty$ as a parameter of $\epsilon.$

By standard triangle inequality we have,
$$|f_\epsilon|\leq \|\rho_\epsilon\|_\infty\|f\|_1=C\epsilon^{-1}.$$

And so it seems to me that $\|f_\epsilon\|_\infty \leq C \epsilon^{-1}$, but is this correct? I am not sure.

Comment: It looks correct.

Comment: It is correct, but notice you can do better (in the range $\epsilon<1$), by using Hölder's inequality to bound $$|f_\epsilon|\leq \| \rho_\epsilon\|_p \| f\|_q= C\epsilon^{-1+1/p}\|f\|_q$$. Since $f\in L^q$ for any $q<4$ we see that we can take any $p>4/3$. I'm not sure this is sharp though.

Comment: @Jose27 thanks for your comment, could you explain why $f\in L^q$ for $q<4?$

Comment: Because $1-x^2=(1+x)(1-x)$ so the singularity at 1 is like $1-x$, which means $f(x)\approx (1-x)^{-1/4}$ for $x\approx 1$ (when approaching from the left).